# What is the meaning of "I elected to be every bit as audacious as she had been towards me."?

Tags: meaning

I read this sentence in [an article](https://www.theguardian.com/theguardian/2002/nov/30/weekend7.weekend1) and it seems I know every word, but just don't know how should I understand the whole sentence. Can somebody explain it?

> I elected to be every bit as audacious as she had been towards me.

Comment: "Elected" means "chose" in this sentence.

Comment: You will have to choose which of the two meanings of [**audacious**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/audacious) fit best in context but the sentence means something like, "I chose to behave exactly as she behaved with me." As Peter said "elected" means "chose" ([**elect**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/elect)).